# the best way to store shape, to later return the topmost shape per specified x, y location (java)

Tags: java, performance, nosql

I need to implement a class that stores shapes. A shape is defined by the following interface:

```
public interface IShape {
    int getLeft();
    int getTop();
    int getRight();
    int getBottom();
    Properties getProperties();
}
```

I need to store these shapes in an efficient manner, and to later return the topmost shape per specified x, y location.
(The solution should support a large number of shapes, and that the bounding shape can be extremely large, so a solution containing a simple collection of shapes isn't efficient enough performance-wise, and a solution containing a map of each point to its corresponding shape isn't efficient enough memory-wise.)

I understand that I have to use a nosql db. But, what is the most effective way to represent the shapes in the db and pull out the shape according to x and y.

Comment: is it performance wise or algo wise, cause the less efficient memory-wise solution using Redis for example, can achieve very high performance even under a lot of keys

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database